# c# EF winforms: role-based access permissions to specific forms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, authentication, authorization

I need to provide some authorization / authentication mechanism to my WinForms app so that users with specific `Role` have a well-defined access-levels to the forms within app.

I have a basic `User` entity in my DB:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public string Login {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;} (encrypted of cource)
    public UserRole Role {get; set;}
}

public enum UserRole 
{   
    Admin,
    Service,
    Operator
}
```

Lets say that my app consist of such forms:

- `MainForm` - the main form with a navigation menu allowing to invoke other forms.
- `FormA` -> invoked from `MainForm`
- `FormB` -> invoked from `MainForm`
- `FormC` -> invoked from `MainForm`
- `SubFormA1`-> invoked from `FormA`
- `SubFormB1`and `SubFormB2`-> invoked from `FormB`
- `SubFormC1`-> invoked from `FormC`

And of course it could go deeper.

Depending on its role, user can do the following:

- `Admin`

  - full access to: `MainForm` and all forms invoked from it
  - no access to `FormC` (and `SubFormC1`)
- `Operator`

  - full access to: `MainForm` and `FormA` (and `SubFormA1`)
  - read-only (preview) access to : `FormB` and `FormC` (and `SubFormB1` `SubFormB2`, `SubFormC1`)
- `Service`

  - full access to `MainForm` and `FormC`
  - read-only (preview) access to `FormB` and `FormA` (and `SubFormA1`, `SubFormB1`)

The entry point to the application would be the `LoginForm` which will be started as first form when the app is run. There user enters his credentials and if they are valid, it is passed to the `MainForm`.

Now questions:

1. How and where to store info about currently logged in user across whole app?

   - as a property (with encrypted data) in `MainForm` ?
2. How to secure each one of forms?

I was thinking about creating an additional entity that would keep the list of form names, to which specific account role has an access but is does not seems that this is a right way.

```
public class FormPermission
{
    public int FormPermissionId {get;set;}
    public string FormName {get;set;}
    public FormPermissionType PermissionType {get; set;}
    public virtual RolePermission {get; set;}
}

public enum FormPermissionType
{
    Full,
    ReadOnly,
    NoPermission
}

public class RolePermission
{
    public int RolePermissionId {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<FormPermission> Permissions {get;set}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: First suggestion is to not relate directly the permissions to the UI. This relationship should be indirect. About implementing it this is a very generic question. You have to enable/disable, show/hide parts of UI. If you can work on the whole form you can make a form to inherith from, that handles the Enabled property of the controls on it.

Comment: Ok, but how and where to store (securely) the information about currently logged in user, and how to determine what kind of access rights does he has for form he tries to access? Should for example the current user role be injected into every form and then evaluated?

Comment: Injection is one way to go or you could store userinfo in a singleton class, here you could also store user settings etc. This way you don't have to pass around a user/access object to every subform.